# Printing list of class object's member variable

Tags: python, list

I have a list of class objects and each object has a variable `val`.

e.g.,

```
class my_class:
  a = 3
lst = [my_class(), my_class()]
```

I would like to print all the object's `val`. How can this be done without iterating through the list?

I tried

```
print(lst.a)
print(lst[:].a)
```

Comment: You can't. You have to iterate over the list.

Comment: @chepner I see. My understanding is looping/iterating is generally very slow in Python because it's not using vectorized operations. Is this also true for lists?

Comment: There's no parallelized attribute lookup. You would need an *immense* list before the benefits would outweigh the overhead of parallelization. Just use a list comprehension; it's plenty fast enough.